# How to get event object value in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have event on change and it return objcet data i need to get specific value from this data but I'm not sure how to.

#### Screenshot

[image: one]

#### Code

```
serviceSelected(event) {
    console.log('service event1: ', event)
    console.log('service event2: ', event.value) // undefined
}
```

**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event in this case is actually en array so you can access your value like this:

```js
serviceSelected(event) {
    console.log(event[0].value)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Pierre Said already given the answer. Here is more details about how Vue works.

Vue uses `this.$refs` to interact with DOM reference, you can use this or use `app.input1` to set vue variable, where `app` is Vue object and `input1` in data element

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data:{
    input1: ''
  },
  methods:{
    method1: function (){
        console.log("Insidide Vue: ",this.$refs['input1'].value);
    }
  }
})

function method1(e){
app.input1 = $(e).val();
console.log("Outside Vue: ",$(e).val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<input @change="method1" onchange="method1(this)" ref="input1">
<div>input1 : {{input1}}</div>
</div>
```